# I'm having trouble changing the background color of a notification

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack

I'm creating an application to listen to music. I use Kotlin and Jetpack Compose. My notification is standard from ExoPlayer. I use the PlayerNotificationManager class to create the notification and the setColor method to change the color of the icons.

I want it to be close to the image.

```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EyVm.jpg)
```

```
package com.mupy.soundpy2.utils

import android.app.Notification.*
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.os.Build
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.SimpleTarget
import com.bumptech.glide.request.transition.Transition
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaItem
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaMetadata
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerNotificationManager
import com.mupy.soundpy2.R
import com.mupy.soundpy2.models.Music
import kotlinx.coroutines.coroutineScope
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.File


class MainPlay(
    private val listFile: List<File>,
    private val context: Context,
    private val listnerCall: (Int) -> Unit,
    private val callPause: (Boolean) -> Unit,
    private val startTime: () -> Unit
) {
    val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build()
    private val utils = Utils()

    private val channelId = "water_notification"
    private val channelName = R.string.app_name
    private val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX
    private val priority = NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX

    private val notificationManager =
        PlayerNotificationManager.Builder(context, 1000, channelId).setChannelImportance(importance)
            .setSmallIconResourceId(R.drawable.baseline_play_arrow_24)
            .setChannelNameResourceId(channelName).build()

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    suspend fun init() {
        coroutineScope {
            if (listFile.isNotEmpty()) {
                player.apply {
                    addMediaItems(listFile.mapIndexed { id, file ->
                        val music = utils.setMusic(id, file.path)
                        MediaItem.Builder().apply {
                            setMediaId(id.toString())
                            music?.let {
                                println(it)
                                setMediaMetadata(setMetaData(it))
                            }
                            setUri(file.path)
                        }.build()
                    })
                    setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes, true)
                    prepare()
                    addListener { listnerCall(id()) }
                }
                showNotification()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getImg(music: Music): ByteArray? {
        var image: Bitmap? = null
        if (music.bitImage != null) {
            image = music.bitImage
        } else {
            // If the image has not yet been uploaded, use Glide to download it
            Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(music.thumb) // Sua URL da imagem aqui
                .into(object : SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    override fun onResourceReady(
                        resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?
                    ) {
                        image = resource
                    }
                })
        }

        val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        image?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream)
        return stream.toByteArray()
    }

    private fun setMetaData(music: Music): MediaMetadata {
        return MediaMetadata.Builder().setAlbumArtist(music.author).setAlbumTitle(music.title)
            .setTitle(music.title).setArtist(music.title).setArtworkData(getImg(music)).build()
    }
    
    private fun showNotification() {
        notificationManager.apply {
            setColorized(true)
            setPlayer(player)
            setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            setUseNextAction(true)
            setUsePreviousAction(true)
            setSmallIcon(R.drawable.baseline_play_arrow_24)
            setUseNextActionInCompactView(true)
            setUsePreviousActionInCompactView(true)
            setUsePlayPauseActions(true)
            setColor(R.color.black)
            setPriority(priority)
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tried many alternatives as I don't know much about jetpack compose.